# JasperReports Error | Trying to load file from System32 folder under windows

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

Having a Swing application using *DynamicReports* (which in turn built over Jasper reports) to print(show and save) pdf file.

The application runs smoothly in *Eclipse* invocation of the *Swing* application, but fails giving `FileNotFoundException(Access is denied)`, when ran as executable jar.

The following stack trace:

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Report_1370232068590_862159.java
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperReport(JasperReportBuilder.java:278) ~[jar:rsrc:dynamicreports-core-3.1.3.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint(JasperReportBuilder.java:308) ~[jar:rsrc:dynamicreports-core-3.1.3.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.export(JasperReportBuilder.java:596) ~[jar:rsrc:dynamicreports-core-3.1.3.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:516) ~[jar:rsrc:dynamicreports-core-3.1.3.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:512) ~[jar:rsrc:dynamicreports-core-3.1.3.jar!/:na]
    at test.firewall.desktop.FirewallAccessTask.makeFirewallPIEChart(FirewallAccessTask.java:130) [rsrc:./:na]
    at test.firewall.desktop.FirewallAccessTask.doInBackground(FirewallAccessTask.java:86) [rsrc:./:na]
    at test.firewall.desktop.FirewallAccessTask.doInBackground(FirewallAccessTask.java:1) [rsrc:./:na]
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error saving expressions class file : C:\WINDOWS\system32\Report_1370232068590_862159.java
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRSaver.saveClassSource(JRSaver.java:153) ~[jar:rsrc:jasperreports-5.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.getSourceFile(JRAbstractCompiler.java:310) ~[jar:rsrc:jasperreports-5.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.createCompileUnit(JRAbstractCompiler.java:282) ~[jar:rsrc:jasperreports-5.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:177) ~[jar:rsrc:jasperreports-5.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:240) ~[jar:rsrc:jasperreports-5.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:490) ~[jar:rsrc:jasperreports-5.0.4.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperReport(JasperReportBuilder.java:275) ~[jar:rsrc:dynamicreports-core-3.1.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Report_1370232068590_862159.java (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRSaver.saveClassSource(JRSaver.java:145) ~[jar:rsrc:jasperreports-5.0.4.jar!/:na]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

enter code herelooks like your file at

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\Report_1370232068590_862159.java` does not have permission for read.

To give it a permission:

> rightclick on a file --> go to Properties --> security --> Edit -->
>   Give your user permission for full control

I think, this might resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question is why it is going to Windows/System32 folder, when I had not configured anything like it in the program. After searching a lot I got one link [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/507805/classpath-jasperreports) where it is classpath issue, then again , how I can I specify Jasper Report jar classpath , in a runnable packaged jar(Jasper Report jar is also packaged). I tried to do everything explained in the article , but of no use. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: On Linux, using an ancient version of Jasper, I encountered a similar problem.
It was trying to write temporary, dynamically generated Java files into /var/lib/tomcat8,   but tomcat didn't have write permissions on that folder.

Essentially it was the same problem on a different platform. 

I totally agree you would want to specify where temporary files get written by Jasper